# How to safely and efficiently remove frames of photo added by software?

Tags: software, image-processing

How to safely and efficiently remove frames of photo added by software?  I'm NOT talking about the physical frame, but the border/frame added by software such as PhotoShop.  I'm particularly interested in knowing how to do this without additionally loosing quality of the digital image file and how to perform this on several dozens of photo efficiently.

Comment: What type of files are you working with?  I'm sure this will have an impact.

Comment: All Jpeg files.

Comment: What software do you have already and what operating system. Photoshop for Mac or PC can obviously achieve this for example.

Comment: If you provided a sample image showing the frame you are referring to, it may help.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that by "frame" your refering to that black / artistic image that goes around your image, like this:

[image]

Is that correct ?

If so, given that all your images have the same frame and have the same size, you can use any command-line program to batch-process your images, croping then to the desired size (i.e., cutting out the frame).

For example, you can use [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop) to do that.